# Tried to allow lambda to access S3 with S3 resource based policy, why didn't it work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I, apparently, naively, Tried to allow any lambda access to read from an S3 bucket.

Never mind if this is a good practice, but for the sake of understanding, I applied the resource policy at the bottom to the S3 bucket (buket, permissions tab, bucket policy).

I thought that his will allow any lambda to read from the bucket. 
but it didn't work.
the only thing that did work, was to set the policy of the lambda to allow reading from this bucket.

My question is, what is the meaning of this S3 resource based policy? the ui allows this, so I assume it's something valid. but what?
thanks!

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject*",
            "s3:GetBucket*",
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because your function **assumes its execution role role**.

Thus you have to **add the function's role to bucket policy**, not the lambda service:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<your-function-execution-role-arn>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you, any idea when using a Service principal would make sense? I looked it up, but it's still not clear to me. it got me to this access denied error :)

Comment: @RoyCa When lambda assumes the role, it uses temporary credentials. Think about this as a temporary IAM user who was created only to execute your function. This user exists only for few hours with the only purpose to invoke your function. Thus you have to give permissions to this temporary user (i.e. role) to act on your bucket. Lambda, as a service, is not involved here.